# Using "nor" in a list without "neither"

Tags: conjunctions, disjunction, neither-nor

This is the classic usage of *neither/nor*:

> I would **neither** hide **nor** run away.

But is the following construction grammatical? (More than two choices, no *neither*)

> I wasn't going to play dead.
>   I wasn't going to hide.
>   **Nor** was I going to run away.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Although the classic rule is to use *neither* and *nor* together, [Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/when-to-use-nor.aspx) writes:

> “Nor” doesn’t necessarily have to appear in a sentence with the word “neither.” “Nor” can start a sentence. For example, if you’ve just mentioned that you don’t usually wake up at 6 a.m. and you want to continue being negative, you can start another sentence with “nor”: “Nor do I like to wake up at 5 a.m.”
>
> Another option is to combine the two negative ideas into one sentence and then start the second part with “nor”: “I don’t usually wake up at 6 a.m., nor do I like to wake up at 5 a.m.”

In your case, you have three options. From the above, it is correct that you don't need to use *neither*. However, in the same article Grammar Girl writes:

> You may also use “nor” if you’re talking about more than two items, but you must repeat “nor” after each element (2). So if you want to add ketchup to your list of dislikes, you have to say, “I like neither hot dogs nor mustard nor ketchup.” It would be incorrect to use an “or” anywhere in that sentence—or to leave out either case of “nor.”

So taking your list as even a single sentence, I think you need to repeat *nor*. So you could write (note grammar change in the second sentence):

> I wasn't going to play dead.
>
> Nor was I going to hide.
>
> Nor was I going to run away.

Comment: I think starting a sentence with "Nor" is akin to starting a sentence with "And". And some people disapprove of that.

Comment: @slim: That's ok in my case, because I'm aiming for a less formal tone.

Comment: I believe part of the problem is that Microsoft Word flags as ungrammatical any use of *nor* unpaired with *neither*, and this leads many people astray.

Comment: I think it would also be okay as written in the question and not start the second sentence with "nor". Why wouldn't it? It consists of three complete sentences, while what I think Grammar Girl means is that if you have a listing of _incomplete_ sentences you have to use "nor" between all of them.

Comment: +1 for drawing attention to the grammar change (viz putting verb before subject after "nor", when "nor" means "and not"). Two usages of "nor" are being discussed here: "neither ... nor", which does *not* entail putting verb before subject, and "nor" meaning "and not", which *does*.

Answer (score 11):

*Nor* can be used without *neither*, as in the following sentences:

> The struggle did not end, nor was it any less diminished.
>   Nor God nor demon can undo the done.

Comment: This is a bit of a different story. "Nor A nor B" is another way of writing "Neither A nor B".

Comment: Yet, the sentence doesn't contain _nor_ and _neither_.

Answer (score 4):

Where the preceding clause or the preceding sentence is already in the negative, as opposed to a positive one following *neither*, it is logical to equate it with a *neither*+[positive]:

*neither*+[positive] ... *nor*

> Neither **was I** going to hide, nor (was I going to) run away.

[negative] ... *nor*

> **I wasn't** going to hide. Nor (was I going to) run away.

I don't know of a proper grammatical explanation of this, though.