# Dependent clause and negation with "nor"

Tags: negation, dependent-clause, negative-polarity-items

I came up with sentences involving dependent clause ("that" clause) and/or negation with "nor" with varying degrees of complexity.

1. He doesn't sing nor dance.
2. I don't think he dances.
3. I don't think he sings nor dances.
4. I don't think he sings nor she dances.
5. I don't think he sings French chanson or German Lied.

   - I (vaguely) recall that we can't use "nor" to connect nouns if it's under "not"

Are these all correct?  Any advices would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you looks at [this question?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161100/is-this-usage-of-nor-correct)  It seems to address the general concept.

Comment: @Minnow Thanks for the pointer, but I found it very hard to apply those "rules" to sentences with dependent clauses.  I want clarification specifically about dependent clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Nor is classically preceded by neither, but not definitively ([see this link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53728/using-nor-in-a-list-without-neither)).  According to the preceding link and [this post](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conjunctions.htm#nor), nor may be used independently from neither.  Based on those guidelines, either of the following would be ok for the first example:

   > He doesn't sing nor dance.
   >   
   > He neither sings nor dances.
2. No issues here.

   > I don't think he dances.
3. This one is fine too.

   > I don't think he sings nor dances.
4. This one sounds a bit clunky.  Refer to the link above, but it's more intelligible by adding a verb for the clause and the changing the tense.

   > I don't think he sings, nor **does** she dance<strike>s</strike>.
5. Fine, but I think [lied](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lied) need not be capitalized.

   > I don't think he sings French chanson or German **lied**.

Comment: Thanks so much.  Negation with dependent clause is confusing because English prefers to (almost mechanically) transform "A does V that B does not W" into "A does not V that B does W".  I found the use of *nor* in "I don't think he sings, nor does she dances." a bit tricky because it should formally be a variation of "I don't V O1 or O2" in which neither *neither* nor *nor* is involved.